# Rails inclusion validation failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, rspec

I have a model that contains two integer columns representing `start_time` and `end_time`. These times are represented by the minute offset for that day.

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :start_time, inclusion: 0..1440
    validates :end_time,   inclusion: 0..1440
end
```

I also have a factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :examples do
        start_time { Kernel.rand(1441) }
        end_time   { Kernel.rand(1441) }
    end
end
```

When I build this object and check if it's valid with RSpec I get errors relating to the
start_time and end_time not being in the list. Checking the values of the object shows that they are properly in range.

I have tried the following to get it to work.

`inclusion: { in: 0..1440 }`
`inclusion: [0..1440].flatten`

---EDIT

In RSpec

```
let(:example_klass) { FactoryGirl.build(:example) }
expect(example_klass).to be_valid ##=> FAILS
```

In rails console

```
t = FactoryGirl.build(:example)
t.valid?
=> true
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There are a few bugs about it, try `Random.rand(0..1440)` instead

Comment: I made the switch to `Kernel.rand(1441)`. The error is still persisting.

Comment: what exact error you run into? I tried you code and it worked perfectly for me for little correction in Rspec: 'expect' code should be exclosed in 'it' block

Comment: And by the way: your 'FactoryGirl.build(:example)' should call factory :example*s*

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    sequence :start_time , (0..1441) do |n|
        n   
    end
    sequence :end_time   , (0..1441) do |n|
        n   
    end 
end
```

and in your Example Factory use

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :examples do
        start_time 
        end_time
    end
end
```

Anything refer to the documentation: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage#sequences-and-associations.

Hope this helps